# gradle dependency tree use of square bracket

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I was looking at the Gradle dependency report for my Android project and came across the following statements.

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
```

What i don't understand is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4`, the use of square bracket and resolving to the same version?

Here is how the dependency has been declared in my project

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it comes from the Maven dependency version specification format - see reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855) and the specific details copied below:

- `(,1.0]` -> x <= 1.0
- `1.0` -> It generally means 1.0 or a later version, if 1.0 is not available. Maven plug-ins may interpret this differently, so it is safer to use one of the other, more specific options.
- `[1.0]` -> Exactly 1.0
- `[1.2,1.3]` -> 1.2 <= x <= 1.3
- `[1.0,2.0)` -> 1.0 <= x < 2.0
- `[1.5,)` -> x >= 1.5
- `(,1.0],[1.2,)` -> x <= 1.0 or x >= 1.2. Multiple sets are separated by a comma.
- `(,1.1),(1.1,)` -> This excludes 1.1 if it is known not to work in combination with the library.

The version in your post is `[11.0.4]`, which based on the above means exactly version 11.0.4. Interestingly, there's a subtle difference between this and simply `11.0.4` - if the specified version is not available for some reason then the former will fail (I assume it causes an error during dependency resolution) whereas the latter will result in the use of a later version (assuming one is available).

As for why it resolves (i.e. you get the `-> 11.0.4` next to it in the dependency graph), I imagine it's because the specified version contains version range reference characters (even though in this case those characters mean it will resolve to exactly that version).